# How to POST JSON to a Google Apps Script with DEV Link

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, post

I have a Google Apps Script Project which I need to receive some request via GET and POST methods. Every goes fine with GET method because I can simulate it via URL in the browser; the problem is in the POST method, I can't do it via CURL it shows a Google permissions error.

Heres my code

```
function doPost(e) {

  let response = ContentService.createTextOutput()
  response.setContent(JSON.stringify({
    response: e
  }))
  response.setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON)

  return response
}

function foo()
{
    var url = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/id/dev";
    var headers = {"Authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()};
    var payload = {
      debug: 'data ok'
    }

    var params =
    {
        "method": "post",
        "contentType": "application/json",
        "headers": headers,
        "payload": JSON.stringify(payload),
        "muteHttpExceptions": true
    };
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params).getResponseCode()
    Logger.log(response);
}
```

I need to debug with a https://script.google.com/macros/s/id/**dev** link. The purpose is not generate a version with each test.

Comment: Provide stacktrace.

Comment: From `the problem is in the POST method, I can't do it via CURL it shows a Google permissions error.`, you want to access to your Web Apps with `doPost` using curl command. If my understanding is correct, can I ask you about the detailed setting of your Web Apps? If my understanding is not correct, I apologize.

Comment: @Tanaike About `detailed setting`, it won't matter, as OP wants to access `/dev` from curl.

Comment: @TheMaster Thank you for your always support. I couldn't notice whether OP wanted to access the developer mode for Web Apps.  In that case, I think that the setting might be `Execute as: Me` and `Who has access to the app: Only myself`. From this, I proposed an answer.

Comment: Yes, the application is configured as, users who have access: 'anyone including anonymous', run on behalf of 'just me'. But the problem is that I can't send a `POST` request from curl, jQuery, Vanilla or any other because Google throws credentials error or something like that. The purpose is to be able to do all the necessary testing of the `POST` without having to create a new version every time I need to change something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to request to your Web Apps with `https://script.google.com/macros/s/###/dev` using a curl command.

In this case, how about the following curl command?

#### Sample curl command:

When your payload is used, it becomes as follows.

```
curl -L \
  -d '{"debug": "data ok"}' \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer ###your access token###" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
"https://script.google.com/macros/s/###/dev"
```

- In order to access to `https://script.google.com/macros/s/###/dev`, it is required to include the access token in the request header. And as a scope, it is required to use for Drive API. For example, it's `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly`.
- If you want to test this, you can retrieve the access token using the following sample script of Google Apps Script. You can use this access token with the above curl command.

  ```
    function getAccesstoken() {
      console.log(ScriptApp.getOAuthToken())
      // DriveApp.getFiles(); // This is used for automatically detecting the scope of `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly`.
    }
  ```
- In this case, `e` of `doPost(e)` is as follows.

  ```
    {"contextPath":"","parameter":{},"postData":{"contents":"{\"debug\": \"data ok\"}","length":20,"name":"postData","type":"application/json"},"contentLength":20,"queryString":"","parameters":{}}
  ```

#### Reference:

- [Taking advantage of Web Apps with Google Apps Script](https://github.com/tanaikech/taking-advantage-of-Web-Apps-with-google-apps-script)

Comment: Your answer is perfect! It works like a I need, thank you so much.

Comment: @Jailer Betancourt Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Answer (score 0):

In the [current state](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#test_a_web_app_deployment), `Test Deployments` are only accessible for users who have edit access to the script. This means that you need to be logged in to access this deployment, and you cannot do it through a cURL request unless you have the necessary cookies to do it.

As a workaround follow these steps:

1. Open [`Google Developer Tools > Network Tab`](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/network/).
2. Go to the page where you have the Test Deployment, `/dev/` endpoint.
3. In the request named `dev`, click the second button and go to `Copy > Copy as cURL`. This will copy the request with all the necessary cookies.
4. In a terminal, make the request by adding `-X POST`.

The response includes the HTML of the desired page.

###### Documentation

- [Google Cookies](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95647?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid)
- [Replay a network request in cURL](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/05/replay-a-network-request-in-curl)